# Hiding NavBar on multiple Database selection

Tags: angular

I have the following problem:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Base de Dados</h3>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="btn-group" appDropdown>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Bases de Dados</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a routerLink="clients" (click)="onDebugClicked()">Debug</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="demoClients" (click)="onDemoClicked()">Demo</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button *ngIf="debugClicked" routerLink="clients"
        class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" button>Clients</button>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <button *ngIf="debugClicked" routerLink="search"
        class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" button>Search</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>



  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button *ngIf="demoClicked" routerLink="demoClients"
        class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" button>Clients</button>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <button *ngIf="demoClicked" routerLink="#"
        class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" button>Search</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>





<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is what i have on the `component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'uidatabase';

  debugClicked = false;
  demoClicked = false;



  onDebugClicked() {
    this.debugClicked = true;
  }

  onDemoClicked() {
    this.demoClicked = true;
  }

}
```

I have the button called DataBase which is a dropdown and allows me to choose between the databases Debug and Demo, however whenever the Debug database is active, i can see both navbar and both buttons instead of just one.

I want to know upon selecting for example the database Debug how I can hide the navbar that contains the information for the Demo database, because right now both navbars are showing with both buttons, how can i achieve this? I already tried multiple stuff with ngIf but am unable to get it right.

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'uidatabase';

  debugClicked = false;
  demoClicked = false;

  isHidden: boolean = true;

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  onDebugClicked() {
    this.debugClicked = true;
    this.demoClicked = !this.isHidden;
  }

  onDemoClicked() {
    this.demoClicked = true;
    this.debugClicked = !this.isHidden;
  }

}
```

Placed the isHidden property as a boolean true by default, then on both databases set the rest as false.

**app.component.html**:

```
<div *ngIf="debugClicked">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button routerLink="clients"
        class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" button>Clients</button>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <button routerLink="search"
        class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" button>Search</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div *ngIf="demoClicked">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-dark" >
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button routerLink="demoClients"
        class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" button>Clients</button>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <button routerLink="#"
        class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" button>Search</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Placed divs on both navbars.